Extension of a harmonic solution from the half open disc to the whole open disc.
I am solving the following question:
Let $B^+$= {${(x, y) | x^2 + y^2 < 1, y > 0}$} be the open half disk. Suppose $u(x, y) ∈ C^2$($B
^+$$)∩C^0($$B¯^+$) satisfies $∆u = u_{xx} +u_{yy} = 0$ in $B^+$ and $u_y(x, 0) =0$. Prove that the extension u(x, y) to B defined as follows is a harmonic
function on all B.
u(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
    u(x,y) & \text{if } y  \geq 0 \\
    -u(x,-y) & \text{if } y < 0
\end{cases}
I tried to approach the problem by working on $y<0$ and by taking $g(x,y)= u(x,u)+u(x,-y)$ on B. This will lead to
\begin{cases}
    ∆g=0 & \text{on } B \\
    g=0 & \text{on } dB
\end{cases}
From here, using green function formula, I can say that $g=0$ on B, and then result follows.
Than case for $y \geq 0$ is trivial here.
My question is that I am not sure if my assumption that $g=o$ on the boundary is correct since I can see that it is true on the x-axis for $g(x,0)=0$, but what about the other boundary of the disc. Is this is a correct way to approach such problem or is there is any other tricks or things I have to be aware of. Thank you!
